# MVC 4 particular record

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing an issue in MVC 4 using asp.net that i want to display a particular record of the login user. The user id is save in the database. How i should pass the user id into a controller other than account controller and how to put the search criteria in the detail view using LINQ query... Kindly do help me.

I have doctor controller in where there are records and its saving with the doctors id. When user login , the record of that particular doctor should be displayed in the doctor view.

Comment: You can store the doctor id in the session when he logged in and then easily can access it from the session in any controller.

Answer (score 1):

Views/Doctor/List

```
@model List<Doctor>

@foreach(Doctor d in Model){

<span>
@Html.AnchorLink(@d.Name,"Detail","Doctor", new{id=@d.Id}
</span>

}
```

Controller

```
public class DoctorController:ControllerBase
{
   public ActionResult Detail(int id)
   {
    var db = new DoctorContext();
    Doctor model=db.Doctors.Find(id)// prepare doc from DBContext EF
    return View();
   }
}
```

In You view folder

Views/Doctor/Detail.cshtml

```
@model Doctor


<label>Name</label>
Model.Name
```

//etc

Answer (score 0):

> How i should pass the user id into a controller

By using `@Html.ActionLink`, for example in your `AccountController/Login` view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("See a Doctor", 
                 "FindDoctor", 
                 "Doctor", 
                 new { patientID = @Model.PatientID })
```